# Sitecore Indexing Error

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, sitecore

I recently got this error when Previewing an Item from Sitecore, and I thought the fix for this was to rebuild the Master Index, however the problem still lies here.

```
Could not find file 'HIDDEN_SITE\data\indexes\__system\segments_k281'.
```

My other thought is now, that there might be some corrupted files in the __system folder, and that needs to be emptied out and have the site rebuild again. However, my concerns here are if I'm gonna lose any site data WHAT SO EVER, if I delete everything in the __system folder and try to rebuild the indexes of Master, Core and Web. The most important part of this process is that content must NOT be changed or deleted in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely remove the indexes and rebuild them, it will never remove any content from the actual databases.

After you remove them, let Sitecore rebuild them by going to Control Panel -> Indexing Manager (or in older versions Control Panel -> Indexing -> Indexing Manager)